# How can I turn this query that uses a join statement into a query that uses a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm given the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal
    FROM Invoices JOIN InvoiceLineItems
        ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
    WHERE InvoiceLineItemAmount > 50
    ORDER BY InvoiceTotal
```

and told to rewrite it using a subquery. I tried writing

```
SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices 
WHERE InvoiceLineItemAmount >  <-----------get error saying the column isn't recognized
    (SELECT InvoiceLineItemAmount
     FROM InvoiceLineItems
     WHERE InvoiceLineItemAmount > 50)
ORDER BY InvoiceTotal
```

but I get an error saying the column isn't recognized?

Comment: The error results from using `WHERE InvoiceLineItemAmount` because `InvoiceLineItemAmount` is not a column in the `Invoices` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access sub-query (or inner query) table's column outside and hence the error.

Please try this:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceDate, i.InvoiceTotal
    FROM Invoices i
    WHERE i.InvoiceID in (select InvoiceID from InvoiceLineItems where InvoiceLineItemAmount > 50)
    ORDER BY i.InvoiceTotal
```

Comment: Thank you that was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The `JOIN` is finding a match when there is a line item with an amount greater than 50.  That suggests a correlated subquery with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceDate, i.InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM InvoiceLineItems ili
              WHERE ili.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID AND
                    ili.InvoiceLineItemAmount > 50
             )
ORDER BY i.InvoiceTotal;
```

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is no longer necessary.  With the right indexes, this should be much faster than your original version.

Comment: Is there a way to write it without using the 'EXIST' and do you know why I'm getting the error. I'm a newbie